# Suitescript 1: Error on removing added line items

Tags: javascript, suitescript

I'm extremely new on Netsuite and Suitescript overall. I have a suitelet and a button that adds and computes discount list (i am getting the Subtotal discount item) on Sales Order and currently trying to remove the discount lines and re-add them again but i am getting an error "This line cannot be deleted, because it is referred to by other records. Before removing this line, remove any discount or markup lines applied to it."

My code goes like this:

```
            for (var i = 1; i <= recordLoad.getLineItemCount('item'); i++) {
                var x = recordLoad.findLineItemValue('item', 'item', subTotalRecord);
                if (x > 0) {
                    recordLoad.removeLineItem('item', x);
                }
            }

            //Remove all the discount lines
            var discountItemInternalIds = [422, 420, 637, 632, 418, 636, 640, 421, 423, 628, 638, 417];
            discountItemInternalIds.forEach(function(discountInternalId) {
                var x = recordLoad.findLineItemValue('item', 'item', discountInternalId);
                if (x > 0) {
                    recordLoad.removeLineItem('item', x)
                }
            });
```

Is there anyway to do this? I've only started learning Suitescript for only 2 months.

Comment: You have remove all the line items are only discount line Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to do it with the help of my amazing superiors hehe.

What we did was get the item type of both the discount and subtotal discount and make sure to remove the discount first and then the subtotal.

```
                for(var x = lineCount; x > 0; x--){
                // var lineType = recordLoad.getLineItemValue('item','itemtype',x).toLowerCase();
                if(recordLoad.getLineItemValue('item','itemtype',x) == 'Discount'){     
                    recordLoad.removeLineItem('item',x);
                }
            }
            // nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'lineType', lineType);

            for(var x = lineCount; x > 0; x--){
                // var lineType = recordLoad.getLineItemValue('item','itemtype',x).toLowerCase();
                if(recordLoad.getLineItemValue('item','itemtype',x) == 'Subtotal'){
                    recordLoad.removeLineItem('item',x);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using suite script 2.0
Then try Below Code
// To get the Line Number
var lineNumber = objRecord.findSublistLineWithValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item',
    value: 233
});

//
var lineNum = objRecord.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'item',
    line: 3
});


var hasSubrecord = objRecord.hasCurrentSublistSubrecord({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item'
});

if(hasSubrecord ){
objRecord.removeCurrentSublistSubrecord({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item'
});

objRecord.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

}
```